# How are they calculating "AssignmentBaseline0Work" in this query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just wanted to understand how they are calculating "AssignmentBaseline0Work".

```
(SELECT        ProjectUID, CAST(MAX(CAST(TaskUID AS nvarchar(36))) AS uniqueidentifier) AS TaskUID, AssignmentUID, TimeByDay, 
                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 0 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineCost ELSE NULL END) AS AssignmentBaseline0Cost, 
                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 0 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineWork ELSE NULL END) 
                                                     AS AssignmentBaseline0Work, 
                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 0 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineMaterialWork ELSE NULL END) 
                                                     AS AssignmentBaseline0MaterialWork, 
                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 0 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineBudgetCost ELSE NULL END) 
                                                     AS AssignmentBaseline0BudgetCost, 
                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 0 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineBudgetWork ELSE NULL END) 
                                                     AS AssignmentBaseline0BudgetWork, 
                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 0 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineBudgetMaterialWork ELSE NULL END) 
                                                     AS AssignmentBaseline0BudgetMaterialWork, 


                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 10 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineCost ELSE NULL END) 
                                                     AS AssignmentBaseline10Cost, MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 10 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineWork ELSE NULL 
                                                     END) AS AssignmentBaseline10Work, 
                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 10 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineMaterialWork ELSE NULL END) 
                                                     AS AssignmentBaseline10MaterialWork, 
                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 10 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineBudgetCost ELSE NULL END) 
                                                     AS AssignmentBaseline10BudgetCost, 
                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 10 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineBudgetWork ELSE NULL END) 
                                                     AS AssignmentBaseline10BudgetWork, 
                                                     MAX(CASE WHEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.BaselineNumber = 10 THEN MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay.AssignmentBaselineBudgetMaterialWork ELSE NULL END) 
                                                     AS AssignmentBaseline10BudgetMaterialWork
                           FROM            dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay
                           WHERE        (BaselineNumber IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
                           GROUP BY ProjectUID, AssignmentUID, TimeByDay) AS Baseline ON Baseline.ProjectUID = dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.ProjectUID AND 
                     Baseline.AssignmentUID = dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentUID AND Baseline.TimeByDay = dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.TimeByDay LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment ON dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.ProjectUID = ISNULL(dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.ProjectUID, Baseline.ProjectUID) AND 
                     dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment.AssignmentUID = ISNULL(dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay.AssignmentUID, Baseline.AssignmentUID)
```

Answer (score 2):

I refactored and formatted the subquery where `AssignmentBaseline0Work` is calculated:

```
 SELECT ProjectUID,
       CAST(MAX(CAST(TaskUID AS nvarchar(36))) AS uniqueidentifier) AS TaskUID,
       AssignmentUID,
       TimeByDay,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 0  THEN AssignmentBaselineCost END) AS AssignmentBaseline0Cost,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 0  THEN AssignmentBaselineWork END) AS AssignmentBaseline0Work,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 0  THEN AssignmentBaselineMaterialWork END) AS AssignmentBaseline0MaterialWork,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 0  THEN AssignmentBaselineBudgetCost END) AS AssignmentBaseline0BudgetCost,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 0  THEN AssignmentBaselineBudgetWork END) AS AssignmentBaseline0BudgetWork,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 0  THEN AssignmentBaselineBudgetMaterialWork END) AS AssignmentBaseline0BudgetMaterialWork,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 10 THEN AssignmentBaselineCost END) AS AssignmentBaseline10Cost,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 10 THEN AssignmentBaselineWork END) AS AssignmentBaseline10Work,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 10 THEN AssignmentBaselineMaterialWork END) AS AssignmentBaseline10MaterialWork,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 10 THEN AssignmentBaselineBudgetCost END) AS AssignmentBaseline10BudgetCost,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 10 THEN AssignmentBaselineBudgetWork END) AS AssignmentBaseline10BudgetWork,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BaselineNumber = 10 THEN AssignmentBaselineBudgetMaterialWork END) AS AssignmentBaseline10BudgetMaterialWork
 FROM dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay
 WHERE BaselineNumber BETWEEN 0 AND 10
 GROUP BY ProjectUID,
         AssignmentUID,
         TimeByDay
```

Essentially, the value of `AssignmentBaseline0Work` is

- the *maximum* of `AssignmentBaselineWork`
- for all rows where `BaselineNumber` is `0`,
- in the table `dbo.MSP_EpmAssignmentBaselineByDay`,
- for each combination of values in (`ProjectUID, AssignmentUID, TimeByDay`).

It helps to think of the query in what's known as the logical execution order:

- First, the rows are filtered (`BaselineNumber BETWEEN 0 AND 10`),
- then grouped by the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause,
- then the maximum of the `CASE` expression is calculated. So you're getting the maximum of `AssignmentBaselineWork` not for all rows, but those rows where `BaselineNumber=0`.